# I am finishing my bachelor degree and want to apply for grad school. How to covince them of my research interest when I have done none before?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am a computer science major aiming for an Ivy League university. I want to pursue research so getting a master's and Ph.D. is only natural. The thing is, I have 0 researches. The reason why I want to get into research is that I  have made many mini-projects and a couple of successful ones. I have tried taking my projects to the next level and I realized all the edits I want to make have something to do with machine learning. I started learning on my own already, but while doing so I really liked the field. Right now I have ideas about ways to improve my existing work and ideas solved with machine learning, which I want to write my thesis about.

Now as you have seen, although I have some successful development experience. my research experience is lacking. so my questions are:

1. How to convince them that I truly like research when everything I have done so far is pure development?
2. should I write my thesis idea in my SOP?
3. the university has three tracks: master's for people with bachelor, Ph.D. for people with master's and MS and Ph.D. track for people with a bachelor who wants to get into masters then Ph.D. I want the last track. Should I apply for the first instead and go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US it is common for a student out of a BS to apply to a doctoral program, sometimes with an MS granted along the way. For such students very little is assumed about research, since few BS degrees stress it very much. The first part of the program is mostly advanced coursework enabling a student to pass comprehensive qualifying exams. Only then, does research become the prime objective.

Your choice of the combined track would be most typical if you have already planned to go eventually for a PhD. Your interest in research is a positive, but not determinative. But having some ideas about what you might want to research is good, but you want to stay flexible about that until you have a dissertation advisor. That choice doesn't need to come immediately and the choice of topic needs to be interesting to the advisor as well as yourself. Some advisors have stronger ideas than others about what their students work on.

Your general attitude here seems good and your lack of research experience is probably no impediment. But note that the competition for any slot will likely be fierce. Stress your accomplishments in the CV and your goals (short and long) in the SoP. Yes, mention any specific research interest, or even a general area. That will help the university match you with an initial advisor, who may or may not be your final dissertation advisor.

Comment: Thank you so much!